# Complexity class of computing a hyperplane

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, linear-algebra

I am concerned with the following algorithm:

As input, it takes n points in n dimensional space in rectangular coordinates.  These n points define an n-1 dimensional hyperplane (we can ignore the infintesimal probability that they don't).  As output, I would like the equation of this hyperplane.

Is there a known algorithm - or at least a known complexity class - for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you're looking for is

```
A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 + ... + A_n x_n + C = 0
```

for some coefficients `A_1` and `C` and for the `x_i` being the rectangular coordinates of a point on the plane. Substitute in the input points and you've got a set of `n` simultaneous equations which you can solve (up to a scale factor).